# Ajaxpro:How to transmit javascript multidimensional array to the ajaxpro method in frontpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, multidimensional-array, ajaxpro

Suppose I have a c# method need array parameter:

```
[AjaxPro.AjaxMethod]
public int Test3(string[,] array)
{
    return array.Length;
}
```

then I define multidimensional array in front page with javascript:

```
   var array = [
        ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
        ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
        ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    ];
```

I want pass the array parameter to the c# method:

```
alert(Get_Data.Test3(array).value);
```

but alert **null**

So how can I pass the array parameter correctly into the c# method?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to use AjaxPro.JavaScriptArray data-type to receive arguments at server side, e.g.:

```
[AjaxPro.AjaxMethod]
public int Test3(AjaxPro.JavaScriptArray array)
{
    return array.Count;
}
```

Comment: maybe you can write your code like code sample in your answer box like this {}